# Clangd server does not search symbols in current working directory

Tags: lua, neovim, clangd

I'm trying to configure clangd to be able to search symbols in nvim working directory, but it still uses only opened buffers.
Configuration:

```
local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }

local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<leader>gD', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<leader>gd', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>', opts)
end

require('lspconfig').clangd.setup{
    on_attach = on_attach,
    filetypes = {"c", "cpp"},
    root_dir = require("lspconfig").util.root_pattern(vim.fn.getcwd()),
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in clangd requires that the project be indexed, which in turn requires that it have a compilation database (`compile_commands.json` file).

The compilation database is usually generated by the build system. See https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#compile_commandsjson for instructions for specific build systems.